# Cannot use a disk drive partition

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am using 500GB hard disk with 465.76GB available. I have installed Ubuntu in 61 GB partition. I have left 402GB for other use. Now I am unable to use that partition memory.

During the startup. It says "The disk drive for /mnt/Memory is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery"][1]

[This is the screenshot of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fElnf.png)

Text of /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9669a356-16ce-4b7a-8a1b-65b3482c4662 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7CB9-E24A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=341759ac-7daf-4fb2-8c21-fd7cb7307688 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/disk/by-uuid/5D75-9449 /mnt/Memory auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/89655141-7e36-4393-8ffa-099cff1a0b16 /mnt/Memory auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c7e33283-12f0-4e00-98d5-9a930a7738da /mnt/c7e33283-12f0-4e00-98d5-9a930a7738da auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: can you add what your `/etc/fstab` looks like in your question?

Comment: @JohnOrion: done

Comment: It looks like you have multiple things set to mount to /mnt/Memory

Comment: How can I change that thing? Little help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. I see a problem

You have two lines that say /mnt/Memory

I believe the one that starts with 5D is wrong .. you can try putting an # at the beginning of that line and save that file

Then type

```
sudo umount /mnt/Memory
```

it should unmount it if its mounted...
then type

```
sudo mount -a
```

and see if you get any errors or if everything goes fine and /mnt/Memory is mounted

Also .. are you trying to mount something at /mnt/c7e.... or is that also linked to the same mount  point .. if so .. you would want to put an # before that too

What you should try now is to make a copy of fstab either with gedit or type

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
```

now type in terminal

```
blkid
```

it will print out a bunch of stuff..

look for /dev/sda4 and make sure the `UUID` is `89655141-7e36-4393-8ffa-099cff1a0b16`

if not and its `c7e33283-12f0-4e00-98d5-9a930a7738da` then what I will do is print out two lines ... you will select one to put into your fstab .. use only one and use the one that matches the UUID for /dev/sda4

Delete all or # before all the lines that say `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Use one of these lines that match your UUID for /dev/sda4

```
#/dev/sda4
UUID=89655141-7E36-4393-8FFA-099CFF1A0B16 /mnt/Memory auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

or

```
#/dev/sda4
UUID=C7E33283-12F0-4E00-98D5-9A930A7738DA /mnt/Memory auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

once you have removed or commented out the old entries and added the proper  new lines .. save  the file and again try `sudo umount /mnt/Memory` then `sudo mount -a` also be aware that this is mounting the partition to /mnt/Memory not /mnt/memory. it is case sensitive so the capital and non capital directories are considered two different directories

Comment: I added # before the 5D line.
After umount statement i got "/mnt/Memory/: not mounted"
and the next statement didn't give any errors. But still I am unable to use /mnt/Memory. I still cannot save anything there.

Comment: copy-pasted the text.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39256/discussion-between-shoham-debnath-and-john-orion).

Comment: blkid didnot return anything